# How to set width In CSS based on a format?

Tags: c#, css, blazor

I work on a Blazor Server Side .NET project.
On my razor page, I have a couple of div's, which display numeric value(s) (can also be Nullable)
I would needs to set the div's width via CSS based on the format, which is used.

Example format could be: "+#0.00;-#0.00"

The width should always be the same, don't matter, which value is set.
For example

-25.50
+3.18

I have created a simple JSFiddle jsfiddle.net/2whox1z8/ sample.
As you can see there, the width of the columsn is much to big.
In my project, I use DevExpress component [link](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/MaskedInput)
I need to show at least 12 input controls in one row.

They get displayed in an hierachial structure.
Because of the hierachial structure, each (child) row get's rendered different and based on the used value, when it shrinks. This makes the UI looking buggy.

This is why, I try to get a fixed width, based on the format I use.

THX in advance

Can this be done?

Thx in advance

Comment: Can you send us a snippet about the HTML part that is concerned please? Depending on the HTML, the CSS might differ

Comment: What width?  Where?  What have you've tried.

Comment: Sounds like OP is maybe trying to build a column of numbers that right-align?  But I don't know why he needs to hard-code a specific width...